# How to find geographically near documents in Redis, like $near in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, redis, geospatial

In MongoDB if we provide a coordinate and a distance, using `$near` operator will find us the documents nearby within the provided distance, and sorted by distance to the given point.

Does Redis provide similar functions?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203913/approaches-to-storing-geospatial-data-in-redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noelkd was right. There is no inbuilt function in Redis.
I found that the simplest solution is to use `geohash` to store the hashed lat/lng as keys.

`Geohash` is able to store locations nearby with similar structure, e.g.
A hash of a certain location is `ebc8ycq`, then the nearby locations can be queried with the wildcard `ebc8yc*` in Redis.

Comment: great  answer! +1 from me!

Comment: I would never ever prefer to use wildcard in redis.
I am using redis with more than 1Crore keys in it & as soon as I run wildcard on my redis server,it got hanged.
In the end restarting server was the only solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

For the people who come accross this old question right now,

Now redis has new geographical commands such as [GEOADD](https://redis.io/commands/geoadd) and [GEORADIUS](https://redis.io/commands/georadius) which covers the question's requirements.